# executing test case for hibernate reactive

Tags: quarkus-panache, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

JUnit call

```
    @Test
    void getTransferDetails() {
        Transfer transferObj = transferRepository.getTransferDetails(transfer);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(transferObj);
    }
```

Repo method

```
    public Transfer getTransferDetails(Transfer transfer) {
        Uni<Transfer> uniTranfer = null;
        Transfer tranfer = null;
        try {
            if(transfer != null){
                StringBuilder sqlQuery = createSqlQuery(transfer);
                Mutiny.Query<Transfer> q = em.createQuery(sqlQuery.toString(), Transfer.class);
                setQueryParameter(transfer,q);
                uniTranfer = q.getSingleResult();
                tranfer = uniTranfer.await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Getting Exception getTransferDetails "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return tranfer;
    }
```

error
`DDL command failed [io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLException: Table 'quarkus.CODE' doesn't exist]`

tried to run the unit test and it gives me an error that table did not found.

Comment: I also see following error
'Detected use of the reactive Session from a different Thread than the one which was used to open the reactive Session - this suggests an invalid integration; original thread [138]: 'vert.x-eventloop-thread-3' current Thread [1]: 'main''